# String updating on a script

Tags: vim, command-line, terminal, vi

I've been trying to make a script using vim to ease my work. 
I have now discovered how to extract the most recent file name out of a folder. Now i need the script to run in terminal, extract that most recent file name, access another file through vi, update line 30 with that new file name information, close that file then send a command to run the program. 
Any clues?

Comment: Please be more specific. How does your folder structure look like? Why does this have to involve Vim (running programs is usually done via the shell, but you've even omitted whether you're on Windows, Linux, or whatever)? What have you tried so far, and what are you struggling with?

Comment: Ok, I use the terminal on Linux and Mac. I use vim because i need it to "read" a file where I can change all the parameters for the simulation, it's called run.params. One section is the input section, where I put the initial solution. In this case, the initial solution is the last one, because I'm carrying on the simulation.
I need vi because I'd like to write a piece of code that then becomes a command - one that I can run and will do that for me (look the most recent solution, and update the run.params file). Am I clearer?

Comment: Well, you're getting there; I still don't fully understand. Instead of commenting, it's better to directly update your question, as this is the main text that people will read.

Comment: just did it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ls -t | awk '{print $1;exit}'` to get the name of the latest modified file...

Comment: this helps a lot!
Now, how can I tell the script to go to row number xxx and substitute the current string by the one that's generated by running ls -t | awk '{print $1;exit}'?

Comment: For the case you want to replace the 9'th line: `sed -i '9s/.*/new content/'`. But you should try searching for some solutions next time before asking.